# Bibtex Won't Show the Author

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

My code goes like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter\normalfont\bfseries}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
{0pt}
{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-24pt}{24pt}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{12pt}{}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{.5in}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.75} 

\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\include{CHAPTERS/Chapter1}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{2}
\end{document}
```

chapter 1.tex:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{section}
The package offers two hooks, \\UrlLeft and \\UrlRight, that by default do
Appending material at left or right\cite{ruth}
nothing but can be redefined to typeset material at the left or right of text. The
material is typeset in the same fashion as the\cite{thomas} text. For example, spaces are ignored
unless one uses \ or specifies obeyspaces as an option. If \cite{jac}the commands are
redefined at the top level, they act on every \\url-like command. See Example 3-1-
34 on the next page for a possibility to restrict their scope.
```

and my .bib file code is this:

```
@Book{cetin,
ALTauthor = {Cetin Kurt and Jürgen Bittner},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {"Sodium Hydroxide" Ullmann's Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry},
publisher = {Wiley-VCH Verlag GmbH \& Co.},
year = {2006},
OPTkey = {•},
OPTvolume = {•},
OPTnumber = {•},
OPTseries = {•},
OPTaddress = {•},
OPTedition = {7},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
@Book{thomas,
ALTauthor = {Thomas F. O'Brien and Tilak V. Bommaraju and Fumio Hine},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {Handbook of Chlor-Alkali Technology Volume I: Fundamentals},
publisher = {Springer Science+Business Media Inc.},
year = {2005},
OPTkey = {•},
OPTvolume = {•},
OPTnumber = {•},
OPTseries = {•},
OPTaddress = {233 Spring Street, New York, NY 10013,
USA},
OPTedition = {•},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
@Book{ruth,
ALTauthor = {Ruth Stinger and Paul  Johnstonand},
ALTeditor = {•},
title = {Chlorine and the Environment-An Overview of the Chlorine Industry},
publisher = {Springer Science+Business Media Dordrecht},
year = {2001},
OPTkey = {•},
OPTvolume = {•},
OPTnumber = {•},
OPTseries = {•},
OPTaddress = {•},
OPTedition = {•},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
@Article{jac,
author = {Jacqueline Fauvarque},
title = {The Chlorine Industry},
journal = {Pure and Applied Chemistry},
year = {1996},
OPTkey = {•},
OPTvolume = {•},
OPTnumber = {•},
OPTpages = {•},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
@Misc{akzo:2009:Misc,
OPTkey = {•},
OPTauthor = {AkzoNobel},
OPTtitle = {•},
OPThowpublished = {https://www.akzonobel.com/ic/products/chlorine/},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTyear = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
}
```

the unexpected output is this:

[image]

please help me...

Comment: Could we have the *real* codes, not images, so we can test without having to re-type everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the ALT prefixes from `author` and `editor` fields, i.e., change `ALTauthor` to `author` and `ALTeditor` to `editor`.

Do this only for fields whose values are not `{•}`, of course, or you'll get some bitter complaints from BibTeX...

By the way, I think the `title` of the `cetin` entry should start with

```
{``Sodium Hydroxide'' Ullmann's...
```

rather than with

```
{"Sodium Hydroxide" Ullmann's
```

For sure, use whatever quotes are appropriate for the main language of your document -- just don't use "dumb quotes".

Comment: Wow! It solved the problem. Thank you so much. it was in TexMaker I just used the insert options in one of the menus. I don't know why they put those words in there. anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: @RicardoVelozJr - I guess the template uses the ALT and OPT prefixes so that BibTeX won't choke on the non-ASCII character `•`. Just remove the ALT and OPT prefixes once you've supplied the appropriate information. Incidentally, it's probably a good idea to remove all fields you don't use for a given entry. If nothing else, it'll reduce clutter.

Comment: I followed your advice sir on {``Sodium Hydroxide'' Ullmann's... and it really did improved. I just started LaTeX yesterday for my thesis thank you for being so considerate in answering my question.

Comment: @RicardoVelozJr - No need to address Jabba the Hutt as "sir". :-)